# Sensitive authentication cookie sent using HTTP

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, https

Let's say there is a website, which after authentication sets a browser cookie. This cookie is sufficient to authenticate a user, so if I were to transfer it to another computer's browser, the website would consider this browser authenticated.

The website uses HTTPS for all communications, except for the following. Whenever a user sends a request to http://domain.tld/ and gets redirected, the sensetive cookie gets sent in the first request, using HTTP (non-secure).

It seems weird to use HTTPS after sending the key using plain text. Is this a security concern, or am I not understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sensitive cookies needs to be protected by `Secure` attribute. Otherwise, it's easy to be intercepted by active network attacker. According to [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.5):

> The Secure attribute limits the scope of the cookie to "secure" channels (where "secure" is defined by the user agent).  When a cookie has the Secure attribute, the user agent will include the cookie in an HTTP request only if the request is transmitted over a secure channel (typically HTTP over Transport Layer Security (TLS)

In this way, sensitive authentication cookie won't be sent in non-HTTPS requests, thus keep it confidential. Example `Set-Cookie` statement is:

```
Set-Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

However, please note `Secure` attribute only protect cookie's confidentiality, not integrity:

> Although seemingly useful for protecting cookies from active network attackers, the Secure attribute protects only the cookie's confidentiality.  An active network attacker can overwrite Secure cookies from an insecure channel, disrupting their integrity.